# Float и int одновременно

Tags: c#, float

Я делаю калькулятор  , но так как числа могут быть и float и int , я не знаю , во что мне конвертировать два числа. Думал что double это и int и float , а нет))

```
Часть кода:
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace MyFirstWinForm
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        int znak = 0;
        string OldDigit;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }


        }

        public void button16_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            znak = 4;
            OldDigit = textBox3.Text;
            textBox3.Text = "";


        }
        private void button9_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            znak = 1;

            OldDigit = textBox3.Text;
            textBox3.Text = "";

        }

        private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            znak = 2;
            OldDigit = textBox3.Text;
            textBox3.Text = "";

        }

        private void button13_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            znak = 3;
            OldDigit = textBox3.Text;
            textBox3.Text = "";


        }
        private void button11_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            double otvet;
            try
            {
                if (textBox3.Text == "0")
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Нельзя делить на ноль!");
                }
                if (znak == 1)
                {
                    otvet = Convert.ToDouble(OldDigit) + Convert.ToDouble(textBox3.Text);
                    string otvet2 = Convert.ToString(otvet);
                    textBox3.Text = otvet2;
                    znak = 0;
                }
                else if (znak == 2)
                {
                    otvet = Convert.ToDouble(OldDigit) - Convert.ToDouble(textBox3.Text);
                    string otvet2 = Convert.ToString(otvet);
                    textBox3.Text = otvet2;
                    znak = 0;
                }
                else if (znak == 3)
                {
                    otvet = Convert.ToDouble(OldDigit) * Convert.ToDouble(textBox3.Text);
                    string otvet2 = Convert.ToString(otvet);
                    textBox3.Text = otvet2;
                    znak = 0;
                }
                else if (znak == 4)
                {
                    otvet = Convert.ToDouble(OldDigit) / Convert.ToDouble(textBox3.Text);
                    string otvet2 = Convert.ToString(otvet);
                    textBox3.Text = otvet2;
                    znak = 0;
                }

            }
            catch
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Ошибка!");
            }


        }
```

К примеру если я введу 2 , потом добавлю к 2.5 будет вот такая 
Ошибка:`System.FormatException: "Входная строка имела неверный формат."`

Comment: добавь текст ошибки, которую ты получаешь, а также добавь строки, которые ты вводишь

Comment: что "это"? и зачем сдвигать? У тебя наверняка ошибка с форматом строки при переводе в double, чтобы это подтвердить, нужно узнать какую ошибку ты получаешь. А чтобы решить, нужно узнать что именно  ты вводишь

Comment: Стоит проверить локаль установленную на твоем компьютере, в некоторых культурах разделитель целой и дробной части не точка, а запятая.

Comment: Я думал что в c# наоборот. Но даже если я запятую введу место точки такая же ошибка

Comment: Что именно наоборот в C#? _Но даже если я запятую введу место точки такая же ошибка_ - проверь на каком именно из ToDouble ты падаешь, и посмотри какое конкретное значение ты пытаешься разобрать. вариантов несколько: неверный разделитель, пустая строка, возможно наличие в строке пробелов в начале или конце

Comment: Смотри , я падаю на том ToDouble , в котором значения znak == тд , а значения знака разное бывает. А наоборот, я думал что в  c# числа float пишутся вот так:  2.5f ; 2.10;.

Comment: _я думал что в c# числа float пишутся вот так: 2.5f ; 2.10;_ - они так и пишутся _в коде_, но ты то разбираешь строку. _Смотри , я падаю на том ToDouble , в котором значения znak == тд , а значения знака разное бывает._ - я не об этом спросил. Когда вываливается исключение оно тебе подсвечивает **конкретный** вызов `ToDouble`, и ты можешь посмотреть какую конкретно строку ты не можешь разобрать.

Comment: Я понял что вы имели ввиду , я нашёл ошибку , я случайно не то что надо было преобразовал в ToDouble.Спасибо.

Comment: "при сложение двух чисел , должен быть ответ" - +100

Comment: ахахахахахахахха.Цитаты великих людей